# android - client server programming

Tags: android, httpclient

i need to develop an application for device management i am beginner in android and java. i want the client to send request for patch to the server and the server sends the requested and i also want to use **web service** to it. i wish to know how to **lay connection between the individual android clients and the server.** pls do send me some sample coding or tutorial???
i do not prefer doing it with php server [Android PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554502/android-php-server)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want PHP and you specifically say you are using Android and Java, why not implement a servlet to host the patches. Then use HttpClient on the android side to send a request over to the servlet and have it respond with the patch.

More on servlets:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

And some simple code for HttpClient:

http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/